# How to add Event in React Functional Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a question about React functional components, specifically about functions in functional components. For instance:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const Component = (props) => {  
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  function handleScroll() {
    let scrollTop = window.scrollY;
  }


  return ()
}
```

Comment: Please post a code or elaborate your questions in detail what you want exactly ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is just a quick demo on how to use `useEffect` to subscribe to event, `useRef` to create element ref for event listener, and `useState` to store the event results.

Please note that this is for the sake of demonstration purpose only. Calling `setState` in every tick of scroll event callback is **NOT** ideal.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  // set default value
  const [scrollTop, setScrollTop] = useState(document.body.scrollTop);

  // create element ref
  const innerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const div = innerRef.current;
    // subscribe event
    div.addEventListener("scroll", handleOnScroll);
    return () => {
      // unsubscribe event
      div.removeEventListener("scroll", handleOnScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleOnScroll = (e) => {
    // NOTE: This is for the sake of demonstration purpose only.
    // Doing this will greatly affect performance.
    setScrollTop(e.target.scrollTop);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {`ScrollTop: ${scrollTop}`}
      <div
        style={{
          overflow: 'auto',
          width: 500,
          height: 500,
          border: '1px solid black',
        }}
        ref={innerRef}
      >
        <div style={{ height: 1500, width: 1500 }}>
          Scroll Me
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here is a working demo in code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-event-listener-demo-fmerz?fontsize=14

Comment: i always declare the handler function like `handleOnScroll` outside the `useEffect` and it's working well for me. but recently i saw other people declare them inside the `useEffect` and it makes me wonder, which way is the right way to declare those handler function that you use for bind with `addEventListener` in react. i'm searching for answers, so far i've got nothing. can you link to a stackoverflow answer or other article about this topic, please?

Comment: @Layhout You should either make use of `useCallback` and write your callback function outside of `useEffect`, or directly write your callback function inside your `useEffect` block. Read more [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/rbhl8y/i_didnt_understand_why_we_need_to_use_usecallback/)

Answer (score 10):

You should add and remove the eventlistener in the same `useEffect`-call. For instance:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const Component = (props) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleScroll() {
      const scrollTop = window.scrollY;
      console.log(scrollTop);
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div />
  );
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const Component = (props) => {  
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  function handleScroll() {
    let scrollTop = window.scrollY;
  }


  return ()
}
```

Comment: You can utilize one `useEffect` block to both add and remove `eventListener`. Your code looks unfinished.

Comment: I am guessing this is not an answer but your code in your question.