# How do I refactor this React component with a listener, to make the component functional?

Tags: reactjs

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial) to connect my React app to Firebase.  However, I'd like to refactor the "withAuthentication" component to be functional, like the rest of my app.

The component I get as a result of following the tutorial is:

```
const withAuthentication = Component => {

  class WithAuthentication extends React.Component {
  
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        authUser: null,
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      
      this.listener = this.props.firebase.onAuthUserListener(

        authUser => { // Valid user
          this.setState({ authUser });
        },

        () => { // Invalid user
          this.setState({ authUser: null });
        },

        () => { // No user
          this.setState({ authUser: null });
        }

      );
        
        
    }
 
    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.listener();
    }

  
    render() {
    
      return (
        <AuthUserContext.Provider value={this.state.authUser}>
          <Component {...this.props} />
        </AuthUserContext.Provider>
      );
    }
  }

  return withFirebase(WithAuthentication);
};

export default withAuthentication;
```

To convert it to be functional, so far I have:

```
const withAuthentication = Component => {

  const WithAuthentication = ({firebase, props}) => {

    const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {

      const listener = firebase.onAuthUserListener(

        authUser => { // Valid user
          setAuthUser(authUser);
        },

        () => { // Invalid user
          setAuthUser(null);
        },

        () => { // No user
          setAuthUser(null);
        }

      );
          
    }, [firebase])
  
    return (
      <AuthUserContext.Provider value={authUser}>
        <Component {...props} />
      </AuthUserContext.Provider>
    );

  }

  return withFirebase(WithAuthentication);
};

export default withAuthentication;
```

Firstly, I'm not sure whether this is the correct approach - happy to be told if not!  Secondly, the original component has the componentWillUnmount() function which removes the listener - I'm not sure how to do this in my functional version.  Can anyone advise?

Comment: Have you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58831750/how-to-add-event-in-react-functional-component

Comment: That's helpful.  So I just do something like return (() => listener()); at the end of useEffect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a return inside the useEffect as in [this post](http://return%20()%20=%3E%20window.removeEventListener(%22keyup%22,%20handleKeyUp);)

```
useEffect(() => {

  const listener = firebase.onAuthUserListener(

    authUser => { // Valid user
      setAuthUser(authUser);
    },

    () => { // Invalid user
      setAuthUser(null);
    },

    () => { // No user
      setAuthUser(null);
    }

  );
      return (() => listener())
}, [firebase])
```

Comment: the link you are using to the post is invalid

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed!  As @Nick said above, the link you gave isn't working, but your solution was enough.