# How to add a keydown Event Listener for a react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, keyevent

I'm trying to 'move' in my 10x10 grid by updating the activeCellId state. However none of the methods I tried works. This is my code.

```
const GridCells: React.FC = () => {
  const gridArray = [...Array(100).keys()];
  const color = [
    "bg-slate-50",
    "bg-slate-100",
    "bg-slate-200",
    "bg-slate-300",
    "bg-slate-400",
    "bg-slate-500",
    "bg-slate-600",
    "bg-slate-700",
    "bg-slate-800",
    "bg-slate-900",
  ];

  const [activeCellId, setActiveCellId] = useState(42);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   document.addEventListener("keydown", updateActiveCellId, false);
  // }, []);  // this doesn't work. the activeCellId is only incremented once, and afterwards the setActiveCellId doesn't get called at all

  const updateActiveCellId = (e: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
    // will eventually be a switch case logic here, for handling arrow up, left, right down
    console.log(activeCellId);
    setActiveCellId(activeCellId + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="grid-rows-10 grid grid-cols-10 gap-0.5"
      // onKeyDown={updateActiveCellId}  this also doesn't work
    >
      {gridArray.map((value, id) => {
        const colorId = Math.floor(id / 10);
        return (
          <div
            key={id}
            className={
              "h-10 w-10 "
              + color[colorId] 
              + (id === activeCellId ? " scale-125 bg-yellow-400" : "")
            }
          >
            {id}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'm trying to update a state in the react component by pressing certain keys. I've tried UseEffect with [] dep array and tried onKeyDown and it also doesn't work. I also tried following [this useRef way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58831750/how-to-add-event-in-react-functional-component) it doesn't work too.

```
const innerRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const div = innerRef.current;
    div.addEventListener("keydown", updateActiveCellId, false);
  }, []);  // this doesn't work at all

  const updateActiveCellId = (e: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
    console.log(activeCellId);
    setActiveCellId(activeCellId + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="grid-rows-10 grid grid-cols-10 gap-0.5"
      ref={innerRef}
    >
    ...
  )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740073/how-to-detect-keydown-anywhere-on-page-in-a-react-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", updateActiveCellId, false);
  
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", updateActiveCellId, false);
  }
}, [activeCellId]);
```

The `[activeCellId]` is the dependency of `useEffect`. Everytimes `activeCellId` changes, the function inside `useEffect` will run.

You had an empty dependency, so it ran on initial component mount only.

The returned function containing `removeEventListner` is executed when the component unmounts (See cleanup function in the docs). That is to ensure you have only one event listener runnign at once.

[Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: oh my godd! thanks so much! I thought i needed to attached the eventHandler once, but didn't care about the state changes at all